# How to call a callback with arguments C#

Tags: c#

Here I am again with another question about `C#`.

So,here are some of the files i have in my project.

```
Configuration.cs
Settings1.cs
Bot.cs
```

Now, the problem is, in `Settings1.cs` I have made a callback (If that is what you call it in C#).

```
public void LoadText(Configuration.BotInfo config)
{
    txtUsername.Text = config.Username;   
    txtPassword.Text = config.Password;
    txtName.Text = config.DisplayName;
    txtPrefix.Text = config.DisplayNamePrefix;
    txtBackpack.Text = config.Backpack;
    txtSell.Text = KeyUserHandler.SellPricePerKey.ToString();
    txtBuy.Text = KeyUserHandler.BuyPricePerKey.ToString();
    lblPrice.Text = value.ToString();    
}
```

As you can see, it is getting the data from the `Configuration.cs` file. What I want to do, is that I wanna call this under the `Settings1_Load callback`.

So, when I type

```
LoadText();
```

It gives me the error that it cannot have 0 arguments.. But what argument can I use here? I am only kind of 'dimming' `Configuration.BotInfo` as config because if I use the full name everywhere, it gives me the non-static and static field error.

Comment: what is `Configuration.cs` ? can you show me some coding of `Configuration.cs` ?

Comment: Short answer is you need to provide a `Configuration.BotInfo` object as a parameter when you call `LoadText`, but as it stands, the question is not clear enough to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Here is the required part - http://pastebin.com/Rf2nE8Hb

Comment: @p.s.w.g - I know that but I do not know what should I provide as a parameter because meh... check the code of configuration.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not getting data from `Configuration.cs` file, it is getting data from that argument which is named `config` and the type of argument is `Configuration.BotInfo`. Probably `BotInfo` is a class which is defined inside of your `Configuration.cs` file.You should pass a `BotInfo` instance to your function to make it work.

For example you can call your method like this:

```
                                // set your  other properties
LoadText(new BotInfo { Username = "user2331", Password="1234", ... })
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am quite new to C#. I have provided the part of the code of Configuration.cs above in which BotInfo comes.. Can you please check it out? here is the link again - http://pastebin.com/Rf2nE8Hb

Comment: but dude, the properties you're tlaking about are getting read in the configuration.cs file from a settings.json file not included in the project.. it is placed in the release fodler.. i cannot assign values to them within the code and properties may vary

Comment: @user3288885 how can I know that? :) Then when you read your values, you should get a `BotInfo` instance and pass it to your method.Your method doesn't read anything.Just changing text values of your textboxes with propertiy values of `BotInfo` instance

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified a bit here and there and I got it working by making public strings and getting the info directly from configuration.cs and then applying them to settings.cs